# Map error : a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++

I have seen the solution of another problem like this one , but it doesn't help me at all. On the line

`studMap[getName()].push_back(getGrade());`

I get the following error :

> A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.

This is my code:

```
class CStudent :public CPerson {
protected: CPerson::name;
protected: CPerson::EGN;
protected: string specialty;
public: CStudent(string n, string E, string s) {
        setName(n);
        setEgn(E);
        setSpecialty(s);
    }
string getName() {
            return name;
        }
};
class CSubject:public CStudent{
protected: string subj;
protected: int grade;
           void setSubj(string s) {
               subj = s;
           }
           void setGrade(int g) {
               grade = g;
           }
           int getGrade() {
               return grade;
           }
           std::map<CStudent, std::list<int> > studMap;
           studMap[getName()].push_back(getGrade());
};
```

How can I pass my value from the method to the map without getting this error and where does it come from ?

Comment: That line has to be inside a function.

Comment: In order to make proposing a solution for your problem possible, please explain what that line is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`studMap[getName()].push_back(getGrade());`

Expressions like this must be inside a method.

You have written it inside a class declaration. In the class declaration, you can only declare/define methods and member data. If you expect that expression to be executed when an object of CStudent is created, you must write it inside the CStudent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement should be part of some method. It's same error as if you tried to write statements in global scope, but current context confuses compiler which expects a declaration here.

Answer (score 0):

You need create instance of the class in-order to use the properties of class. i.e. make instance of CSubject to use studMap. The error you're seeing says that 'Non-static functions have to be called through the objects'.